# Contiki ctimer clock does not update

Tags: c, timer, embedded, contiki

I'm working on implementing a new route protocol on contiki 2.7, and I just rewrite the rpl files in core/net/rpl. I use example/ipv6/rpl-udp/udp-server and udp-client to test my route protocol on cooja with Sky mote. However, when I use the ctimer_set function, it never goes to callback function. The code is shown as below:

```
void *dis_timer_init_ptr;
void rpl_init(void){

  clock_time_t waiting;           
    srand((unsigned)clock_time());
    waiting =  (uint32_t)random_rand() % 60;   //waiting for 1-60 s randomly    
    PRINTF("rpl_init, waiting  %d\n",(unsigned long)clock_time());
    dis_timer_init_ptr = &dis_timer_init;
    ctimer_set(&dis_timer_init, CLOCK_SECOND,
           handle_dis_timer,dis_timer_init_ptr);
}
```

and

```
static void
handle_dis_timer(void *ptr){            
  struct ctimer* ct_ptr = ptr;
  clock_time_t waiting;
      dis_output(NULL);
      srand((unsigned long)clock_time());
      waiting =random_rand() % 60;   //waiting for 1-60 s randomly
      PRINTF("handle_dis_time, waiting  %d\n",(unsigned long)waiting);
      if(has_prefix == RPL_NO_PREFIX)
             ctimer_reset(ct_ptr);
```

}

Here rpl_init is used in exactly the same position as originally in tcpip.c,line 823. With the Variable Watcher of Cooja I found that the seconds is 0 after simulation start all the time. If I use original RPL files, clock updates properly. So does anyone know what has happened? Or is there anyone who has similar experience? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `dis_timer_init` in your code? The first argument to `ctimer_set` should be a pointer to `ctimer` structure.

Comment: Also, in Contiki you're supposed to use `random_init(seed)`, not `srand(seed)` because the Contiki random-number generator might be implemented without using libc on some hardware platforms.

Comment: Well, dis_timer is defined as `static struct ctimer dis_timer_init;`, it is a ctimer pointer. Thank you for your advice, I will try random_init(seed). I just use sky platform.